# Discord.py bot inventory

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

https://paste.pythondiscord.com/okayudumad.py
This is a snippet of my bot code (dictionary).

I'm trying to make a game discord bot, and I'm currently working on items. The bot itself runs fine, but the problem with my code right now is that everyone shares a single inventory, and I can't figure out how to fix this.

I've attempted to create a separate json file to store inventories and making a dictionary of users, but nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: jonrsharpe thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: Note **in the question itself**

Comment: please type in your code in the question instead of posting a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's doable, but you need to structure your data just a bit differently. Since you are working with a dictionary, storing it in a file in JSON is fine, though beware that if you are planing on hosting your bot online, local files are not a good option. You could either store them in an array, or have a root object to house all users under. As for the identifiers it's most logical to use an users Discord ID.

Option 1

```
[
  {
    "123456": {
      "values": 1
    },
    "543451": {
      "values": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Option 2

```
{
  "users": {
    "123456": {
      "values": 1
    },
    "543451": {
      "values": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively what you could do is store it in a database, under a users table (with again the Discord ID as the PK). I find this a lot easier myself, as the structure is easy to expand.